# Map angular routes to an Type whose keys are the path properties

Tags: angular, typescript, mapping, typescript-generics

I have routes like this

```
const routes = [
  { path: 'path1' },
  { path: 'path2', children: [{ path: 'path3' }] },
] as const;
```

and I want a map like that

```
type map = { path1: {}; path2: { path3: {} } };
```

So, how can I correct the type below in order to get the map from the route as provided above?

```
type MappedRoutes<TRoutes> = {
  [K in keyof TRoutes]: TRoutes[K] extends {children: unknown, path: string, }
    ? {TRoutes[K]['path']: MappedRoutes<TRoutes[K]['children']>}
    : TRoutes[K]['path'];
}
```

That is `MappedRoutes<ArrayIndexes<typeof routes>>`, as below should return `{path1: {}; path2: { path3: {} } }`;

```
const array = [] as const;
type keyOfArray = keyof typeof array;
type ArrayIndexes<TArray> = Exclude<keyof TArray, keyOfArray>;

type mapped= MappedRoutes<ArrayIndexes<typeof routes>>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write it like this:

```
type Routes = readonly { path: string, children?: Routes }[];

type MappedRoutes<T extends Routes> = {
    [K in T[number]["path"]]: (Extract<T[number], { path: K }>['children'] extends infer R ?
        R extends Routes ? MappedRoutes<R> extends infer O ? {
            [P in keyof O]: O[P]
        } : never : {} : never)
}
```

You can verify it works the way you want (although without the intervening `ArrayIndices`):

```
type Mapped = MappedRoutes<typeof routes>
/* type Mapped = {
    path1: {};
    path2: {
        path3: {};
    };
} */
```

If `T` is assignable to `Routes`, an array of `{path: string, children?: Routes}`, then `MappedRoutes<T>` has the keys in `T[number]["path"]`... where `T[number]` is the union of the types of elements of the array, and `T[number]["path"]` is the union of their `path` properties.

Then, for each one of these keys `K`, we get `Extract<T[number], {path: K}>['children']`, which is the `children` property corresponding to that `path`.  (`Extract<T[number], {path: K}>`) is takes the union of elements of the array and extracts just the one assignable to `{path: K}`.  And then we get its `children` property).

We inspect this `children` property.  Is it a `Routes` itself?  If so, recursively produce `MappedRoutes` of it.  There's a fair bit of conditional type inference happening there, but that's mostly so I can store types into type variables rather than rewrite them.  `R` is the `children` property, and `O` is the mapped `children` property if it exists.  I walk through `O` so that the `Mapped` type is eagerly recursively expanded to its final form instead of leaving it like `{path1: {}, path2: MappedRoutes<readonly blah blah yuck>}`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlAphGBeGBtAsAKBiJgG8YAHAQygAsAuGAcitoEZGYBfAGgONIrV6TFjQBMjbjGA0AlgBsAJnBRgG2MqIbMhAZg6cAul175jldKEhQA3AQJQAnuRQwASklTosKyovDyjgJaMNBwsmAA5lIyCsqqAPwMHshoXNiGdvgOzq4AspTkLoopXgA8ACowKAAeqGCK6KVoAHyYpHzE2ADSMBEwFdhgiAC2AEYocIbYAESiM4aGDAAUAKJ1cJTAUJVDoxNTUppCDL2cLdiMsUoqYIzGtfWNfWAAZpPuMAmd-ERu1XVVM9mugEjACkUUCVPGgym42o8gegIu84DAAPJfDqEX647AABReMAA1ihHCBXhilhiCYYfr9ODAGGAUAA3D4MEiM5lsyYASgInHs+CcLnBhWK7QhxRBZVFKAp8BhEBaBAA9AAqGDy8WQxTtEj00SsTmcLL8URiTkwekWvSm83EM2CmAatVAA)